# Get the query string value from a URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL like

```
http://something.com?acess_token=ashv6786sdjfhjd
```

When I click on that link, how to get the **access_token** from that link using **Javascript**?

Comment: Hi, here is described solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters?page=1&tab=active#tab-top

Comment: please try searching before asking

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
var Yoururl= "http://something.com?acess_token=ashv6786sdjfhjd";
var acessToken=Yoururl.split('?')[1].split('=')[1];
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/7wn4wqr8/1/)

For url parameter see old so question from given link. 
[Get url parameter via jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of the access_token you mean this:

> ashv6786sdjfhjd

Then here's a quick solution. Hope it helps!

```js
var str = "http://something.com?acess_token=ashv6786sdjfhjd.when";
var accessToken = str.split("=")[1].split(".")[0];
console.log(accessToken);
```